# Checkbox edit is not working in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
{
    name: 'hidden',
    editable: true,
    formatter: "checkbox",
    editoptions: {
        value: 'True: False'
    },
    edittype: "checkbox",
    index: 'hidden',
    width: 40,
    sortable: true,
    sorttype: 'int',
    align: "center"
},
```

This code is working in jqgrid, is some time editable in chrome but not editable in firefox and safari, etc.
Plz help me thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{name: 'hidden', editable: true, formatter: "checkbox",  edittype: "checkbox", index: 'hidden', width: 40, sortable: true, sorttype: 'int', align: "center",formatoptions:{disabled:false}},
```

formatoptions:{disabled:false}  is missing